# how to make vim ping on the same port where Eclim is installed?

Tags: vim, eclim

My .eclimrc file allows eclim daemon to use port 9091 of localhost. But on launching Vim I get the error

```
unable to connect to eclimd (port: 9092) - connect: Connection refused
```

on changing the .eclimrc port to 9092 the vim start pinging on 9091.

What could be the possible solution?

Here is my ~/.eclimrc configuration

```
# Bind eclimd to all interfaces 
nailgun.server.host=127.0.0.1

#Language Used
user.language=en

# Specifies the port that nailgun / eclimd listens on for client requests.
nailgun.server.port=9091

# Specifies the workspace directory to use
# See $ECLIPSE_HOME/configuration/config.ini for other osgi properties.
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace_juno

# increase heap size
-Xms128M
-Xmx1024M

# increase perm gen size
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://eclim.org/eclimd.html#multiple-workspaces):

> ### Multiple Workspaces
>
> Running eclim against more than one eclipse workspace can be accomplished by running multiple eclimd instances. You must configure each instance to run nailgun on a unique port and supply the path to the workspace you which that instance to use. Once your eclimd instances are up and running the vim client will automatically determine which server to send requests to based on your context. In some cases you may be prompted for which workspace to use if one cannot be determined for you

The linked page shows example configurations.

Comment: I have defined my workspace osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace_juno

Comment: Secondly when you do _:PingEclim_ on Vim and you have multiple workspaces, then it gives you options to select any of the workspace listed (0-3) input as numbers